# recursive method doesn't work

Tags: java, algorithm, list, recursion, linked-list

I have a problem with a recursive method that fills a structure `LinkedHashMap<String,LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>>`. I don't know if the call of function in the last return is in the right place - i have tried putting it in three different places now:

```
public static LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> GetXMLRegularExpression(
        Node node, LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> a) {
    List<Element> children = getChildren(node);
    List<String> childrenString = ConversionString(children);
    List<String> Clear = RemoveDuplicate(children);
    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> lhm = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

    // System.out.println(childrenString);
    if (!isLeaf(node)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Clear.size(); i++) {
            int count = NumberOfAppear(childrenString, Clear.get(i));
            lhm.put(Clear.get(i), count);
        }
        a.put(node.getNodeName(), lhm);
        return a;

    } else {
        lhm.put(node.getNodeName(), 0);
        a.put(node.getNodeName(), lhm);
        return a;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < children.size(); j++) {
        return GetXMLRegularExpression(children.get(j), a);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `isLeaf(node)` do? I can imagine, but it's helpful to see the code for methods you call which may be unfamiliar to people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks problematic. You embedded the "return" statement in a loop, which is strange. Are you trying to return multiple value from this function? On the 1st iteration of the loop, the "return" statement will be executed which ends execution of this function.

Comment: that's true too, but the code isn't even reached; both the "if" and "else" have a return statement, so one of those returns before the for loop can be executed.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for pointing out this. I jumped to the last return after I read the question. :)